# Add values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a table with two attributes

```
Staffnumber     Name
```

Now I want to add a new staff member into this table, for example: Christian, and Staffnumber is the current max Staffnumber + 1. (Assume I have til now 20 staff members, then Christian would be number 21)

How could i do that, without knowing how many staff members I had? Is there any way to make SQL numbers the Christian as 21?

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use? (MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc)? The feature you are asking for is often known as an auto-incrementing ID or identity column, and is supported by any rdbms via different means.

Comment: Have you tried the INSERT statement?

Comment: MySQL, 

I'm just learning the language,

My guess it would be

INSERT into Table
VALUES(Staffnumber, "Christian")

But idk how to work out the staffnumber,

Comment: Did you set auto increment for your column?

Comment: Your guess is syntatically incorrect: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @AnzDevil i dont think we learned that, i'm just doing homework actually.

Comment: So all you need to do insert Christian as staff number 21?

Comment: @AznDevil92 its just an example, like you said, i want the auto increment thing. Is there anyway to do that without modifying the table ?

Comment: In MySQL, you should define the `Staffnumber` column as `INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`. Doing so will automatically assign incrementing numbers. It is not safe to manually add 1 to the last value, due to concurrent inserts. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 2):

Making a call to the table to count the records should achieve sort of what you're looking for. Forgive my syntax but it should be something along these lines...

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (STAFF_NUMBER, NAME) VALUES ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME) + 1, "Christian");
```

Keep in mind if you delete staff members and add more later this won't work because the count will be off.

If you make your STAFF_NUMBER column a primary key, you shouldn't have to specify this value at all when entering new values, it should auto-increment and assign a random ID to the staff member.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (NAME) VALUES ("Christian");
```

Comment: Oh how nice, thank you !

Comment: No problem. I think the best approach would be to use an auto-increment system so that your counts don't get messed up, but if you need to use a specific ID that is related to the number of staff members, you might be able to do a "if there is no staff member with ID x, use that x, otherwise how many staff members are there currently" sort of logic.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no auto-increment on your column, then you would just do a simple INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Staffnumber, Name)
  VALUES (21, 'Christian')
```

Also here is a link to set AUTO_INCREMENT for your column for MySQL:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: thank you :D i got this.

Answer (score 1):

***Increment***

So if you don't have auto increment. You will want to select the `COUNT()` from Staffnumber.
`SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 From Table;`

***Inserting***

Now you also want to insert a new record into the table.

`INSERT INTO Customers VALUES(1,"Christian");`

But the problem with this is that it will only `Staffnumber` of 1. So you need to combine both of these.

***Final***

`INSERT INTO Table VALUES((SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM Table),"Christian");`
`INSERT INTO Table VALUES((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table) + 1,"Christian");`

Comment: this is actually what i'm looking for, without altering the collumn into auto increment ! 

Much thanks !

Comment: May I ask you why that is "SELECT MAX(Staffnumber)+1 FROM Table"
but not "SELECT MAX(Staffnumber) FROM Table +1 " ? 
I think it makes more sense that i select the number first and add it with 1 ?

Comment: @TuấnPhạm The max function is defined as. _The SQL MAX function is used to return the maximum value of an expression in a SELECT statement._ So if you were to try the second option you would get a error. So this function just finds the max value and returns it, So you would want to add one once it is selected.

Comment: got it ! thank you , again !

Comment: @TuấnPhạm Sorry I though you were talking about something different. `INSERT INTO Table VALUES((SELECT MAX(Staffnumber)+1 FROM Table),"Christian");` and `INSERT INTO Table VALUES((SELECT MAX(Staffnumber) FROM Table) + 1,"Christian"); ` have the same desired results.

Comment: @TuấnPhạm I updated it as you would want the function `COUNT()` not `MAX()`.

Comment: many thanks, your answers are really helpful :)